# PHP: Redirect output of a bash command into default logger

Tags: php, bash, logging, stream, exec

I have a class executing commands in my console. This class is defined with a `LoggerInterface` defined from `@logger.handler`.

I want to execute commands in my bash but:

- I dont want to display result in default stream
- I want to put result in the default log file (defined by $logger), e.g. app/logs/application.log

The main method of this class looks like:

```
$command = $command . " > 2>&1";
$returnVal = null;
$output = [];
exec($command, $output, $returnVal);
$this->logger->debug($output);
```

I added `> 2>&1` to display nothing in the current stream, and because I don't know how to get `app/log/application.log` from the $output...

The issue is that I have nothing in my app/config/application.log!

Do you know what I've missed ?

Comment: have you tried
`$command = $command . " > \"app/config/application.log\""`; ?

Comment: @Tarek I'm pretty sure it will work, but I don't want to set this path hardcoded, because it can be different when you run your application in dev mode, or overrided from dependency injection.

Comment: then `$command = $command . " > \"" . $logger . "\""` ?

Comment: @Tarek I don't do define by myself `$dir`. I want to get it from the application, but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: you said you have the value stored in `$logger`

Comment: @Tarek `@logger` is a LoggerInterface, not a path.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not capturing anything in the output because of `> 2>&1`

```
//$command = $command . " > 2>&1";
$returnVal = null;
$output = [];
exec($command, $output, $returnVal);
for ($i=0;$i<count($output);$i++)
    $this->logger->debug($output[$i]);
```

if the debugger creates several timestamps for each one and it is not the desired output then use this:

```
$returnVal = null;
$output = [];
exec($command, $output, $returnVal);
$result=""
for ($i=0;$i<count($output);$i++)
    $result.=$output[i]."\n";
$this->logger->debug($result);
```

Comment: This solution works but only return last line of the exec command... Not as expected :(

Comment: This solution displays all the result in console when I run it.

Comment: just attach it to the debugger man, do i have to edit everything for u :P